# Jazzy GridView is not responding on click event

Tags: android, listview, animation, gridview, animated

I am using Jazzy GridView for populating my gridview as it has nice animated behavior.But after installing the sample project i noticed that it doesn't respond on click event.
Please anyone tell me is there any bug and how to fix it ?

https://github.com/twotoasters/JazzyListView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution:-

download the solved project from [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/i2sfzqjr604f8gv/JazzyListViewSample_Solved_ClickEffect.zip?dl=1&token_hash=AAE-Q_K-_WnZsAOrc9bu0UWnlWZex4dCQyAFlYAK8WypVw)

Must use JazzyListView Library to use the project.
Solved Both Grid and ListView. Enjoy the Jazzyness :-)